# Why declaring @+id is allowed in other than id attributes

Tags: android, xml, layout

So lastly I have had to rebuild not my XML layout file for android app. And I saw constructions like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rev_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rev_arrow">
        <!-- some stuff in here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rev_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is really annoying when I see that someone using @+id in not android:id attribute. When any developer will want to search this id he will find LinearLayout first instead ImageView.
My question is why google allow it? Is there any particular reason for it and I just didn't know it?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Where LinearLayout is? Below another control with ID rev_arrow? ;)

Comment: The classic rule was that the first occurrence of the ID value, top-down, needed the `+` sign. Second and subsequent occurrences could drop it off. It never had anything to do with the attribute name (e.g., `android:id` versus something else).

Comment: It's called `anticipated id referral`. It's **not a best practice**. You better define the ids you will later refer *before** the View which will refer them.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have never said it have anything to do with attribute. I just said that android studio should at least warn you if you declare (@+id) same id in same file several places. My first idea was to maybe tie it to the id attribute but as@theMfroma point it is not best option. Still declaring same id several times in same file should be forbid IMO.

Comment: "I have never said it have anything to do with attribute" -- yes, you did ("It is really annoying when I see that someone using @+id in not android:id attribute").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason:
Sometimes, you have to set a View A relative to the position of a View B which is declared later in the XML-file (which is the case in your example. The LinearLayout is "View A" and the ImageView is "View B").

Imagine, the code you've got a problem with

```
android:layout_below="@+id/rev_arrow"
```

would look like this instead:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/rev_arrow"
```

The android:layout_above would be useless if you couldn't declare an id inside it.

Because it was mentioned in a few comments:
You have to use the "plus"-sign always at that place, where the id is first declared in the layout-file (from top to bottom). It is independet from the attribute, like "id" or "layout_below".

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid use of the ID, as it tells the layout manager that the view identified by `id/rev_main` view is to be placed below the view identified by `id/rev_arrow`.

So in places other than `android:id`, the ids are used as references to views identified by the respective id.

Comment: Bu isn't reference is @id? Without plus sign?

Comment: You have to use the "plus"-sign always at the place, where the id is first declared in the layout. It is independet from the attribute, like "id" or "layout_below".

Comment: @Glorifind because the referred id has not yet been created